# python questionTypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python

I want to insert into mysqldb only one line.

the pycode is:

```
value1=['4444444555','1231f2d3sa']
cur.executemany('insert into mydb1(title) values(%s)',value1)
```

the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python27\pc\db1.py", line 20, in <module>
    cur.executemany('insert into mydb1(title) values(%s)',value1)
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 255, in executemany
    self.errorhandler(self, TypeError, msg)
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cursor.executemany()` expects a sequence of sequences, ie:

```
values=[('4444444555',), ('1231f2d3sa',)]
cur.executemany('insert into mydb1(title) values(%s)', values)
```

Note that this is fully documented : https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#executemany